# Control operator as optional parameter in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to run a program optionally in the background. Is there a way to pass a control operator optionally. Something like:

```
if some_condition
    bg=&
fi

myprog $bg
```

However, as I can see, bash is (rightly) treating `$bg` as an argument to `myprog`. I am trying to get `myprog` running in the background.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `eval myprog $bg`?

Comment: Why not "if some_condition; then myprog &; fi"?  Otherwise, you can use eval.

Comment: I was going to suggest `eval`, but `eval` is `evil`. It would be easier and safer to use and `if` statement.

Comment: @RobertSeaman can you kindly elaborate on `eval is evil`?

Comment: @ArunPrakashJana When using `eval` you have to be very careful, as you're able to run unwanted commands (especially if you're handling user input). Avoid `eval` where possible and only use it when you need to.

Comment: @RobertSeaman my use case is, I am writing a script which will be invoked from nnn (https://github.com/jarun/nnn). Users may modify it to enable apps started in bg/fg but there's no supported use case of running it with custom user input.

This bash script is equivalent to my config file.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if some_condition
then 
  myprog &
else
  myprog
fi
```

Comment: I am doing this already. However, curious to know if there's a way to handle this in one line without conditional checking.

Comment: If your intention is to only specify `myprog` once then I have added a solution below, however, if you're only running `myprog` once, then James' answer would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in favour of James Brown's answer, however, if you're only looking to specify `myprog` once, then maybe you can use a function to determine if it should run in the background or not. However, this does mean you'll be writing more lines initially, but you could benefit from this if you're potentially running a lot in the background...

```
run_in_background=false

run_cmd () {
    echo "Running $@"
    if $run_in_background; then
        "$@" &
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

if [[ "$1" == '--bg' ]]; then
    run_in_background=true
    shift
fi

run_cmd "$@"
```

Then you can run it like so:

```
./script.bash --bg sleep 1
```

Or if you could run it within the script itself:

```
... (Continuing from inside the script above)
run_cmd sleep 1
run_cmd echo hello
wait  # Waits for background processes to finish
```

And then you can determine if the commands being passed to `run_cmd` will be in the foreground or background by either omitting or using the `--bg` flag.